How can I configure the Firebase Cloud function emulator so that my function receives messages from a real cloud topic
I want to be able to test my cloud function locally in the Firebase emulator with it receiving messages from an actual topic in the Firebase cloud environment (not from the Firebase PubSub emulator).
I have configured the GOOGLE_APPLICAITON_CREDENTIALS env var to point to my admin credentials as outlined here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional
My Firebase functions app looks like :
initializeApp();

export const playBillingMessageReceived : CloudFunction<CloudEvent<MessagePublishedData>> 
  = onMessagePublished(PLAY_BILLING_TOPIC, messagePublishedPlayBillingHandler);

When I execute firebase emulators:start --only functions the emulator starts up, but the console shows:
+  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: playBillingMessageReceived.
i  functions[us-central1-playBillingMessageReceived]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.

And messages posted to my topic are never received by my function.
How can I get my function in the Firebase emulator to connect to and receive messages from a topic in the cloud?

Hi William, may I know are you having similar issue as mine (I am using Python) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78945003/function-ignored-because-the-pubsub-emulator-does-not-exist-or-is-not-running May I know, have you found a solution? Thanks.

My issues is different to yours. AFAICT your pubsub emulator is starting.

You cannot trigger a Firebase Cloud Function running in the emulator via message published to a non-emulated topic in Cloud Pub/Sub. As stated in the documentation:

The Cloud Functions emulator supports background-triggered functions from the following sources:

Realtime Database emulator
Cloud Firestore emulator
Authentication emulator
Pub/Sub emulator



Hmm that is disappointing. I had missed the meaning of that piece of doco amongst all the warnings to be careful not to access real resources while running the emulator.
It will seriously slow down development to have to deploy these functions in order to iteratively develop them. What is the standard/recommended work around?

Why is publishing messages to the emulator not an option?

Sure I could. But we are talking about many dozens of variants with time sensitive data that I will need to first capture from the original source and then copy into the emulator pub sub. Very manual and tedious.

Isn't there any good automated way to get messages from a real cloud topic into the emulator? NB going via the emulator PubSub is fine. Surely this isn't an uncommon requirement for dev.

It is not something I have seen come up before. There is no automated way to do it. You could write a small application that pulls from a real subscription and republishes to the emulator.
