"function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running." - Despite admin credential has been setup
I have the same issue as described in Firebase functions won't see pubsub emulator running locally
As stated in the answer, the solution is to setup admin credential.
I have followed the step. But, I am still getting the same error.
This is the log, to show admin credential (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) has setup.
However, error "function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running." is still being seen.
(venv) yccheok@Yans-MacBook-Pro functions % export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID="YYY"; 
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8085";
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/yccheok/yocto/ZZZ/firebase/functions/YYY.json";
firebase emulators:start
(node:4337) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, pubsub, storage
⚠  emulators: It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project YYY. This may result in unexpected behavior.
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, dataconnect
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /Users/yccheok/yocto/ZZZ/firebase/functions/YYY.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/yccheok/yocto/ZZZ/firebase/functions" for Cloud Functions...
 * Serving Flask app 'serving'
 * Debug mode: off

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8081
Press CTRL+C to quit

127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2024 14:50:12] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2024 14:50:12] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -

/bin/sh: line 1:  4426 Terminated: 15          python3.12 "/Users/yccheok/yocto/ZZZ/firebase/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py"

✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: cloud_storage_trigger, on_request_example, simple_youtube_trigger, youtube_request.
✔  functions[us-central1-cloud_storage_trigger]: storage function initialized.
✔  functions[us-central1-on_request_example]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/YYY/us-central1/on_request_example).
i  functions[us-central1-simple_youtube_trigger]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
✔  functions[us-central1-youtube_request]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/YYY/us-central1/youtube_request).

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub        │ 127.0.0.1:8085 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ 127.0.0.1:9199 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
 

Do you have any suggestion how I can overcome this? Thanks.
This is how the functions look like.
main.py
@https_fn.on_request(
    cors = options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins = ["*"],
        cors_methods = ["POST"],
    )
)
def youtube_request(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    # Check if the request method is POST
    if req.method != 'POST':
        return https_fn.Response(json.dumps({"error": "Only POST requests are allowed"}), status=405)

    # Extract data from the request
    request_json = req.get_json(silent=True)
    if request_json and 'uid' in request_json:
        uid = request_json['uid']
        doc_id = request_json.get('doc_id')
        filename = request_json.get('filename')
        language = request_json.get('language')
    else:
        return https_fn.Response(json.dumps({"error": "Invalid request data"}), status=400)

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

    # Publish message to Pub/Sub
    project_id = "XXX"
    topic_id = "youtube"
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

    # List all topics in the project
    topics = list(publisher.list_topics(request={"project": f"projects/{project_id}"}))

    # Check if the test topic exists
    youtube_topic = next((topic for topic in topics if topic.name.endswith(f'topics/{topic_id}')), None)

    # If the topic doesn't exist, create it
    if not youtube_topic:
        topic = publisher.create_topic(name=topic_path)
        print(f"Created topic: {topic.name}")
    else:
        print(f"Topic already exists: {youtube_topic.name}")

    message_data = {
        "uid": uid,
        "doc_id": doc_id,
        "filename": filename,
        "language": language
    }

    data_str = json.dumps(message_data).encode("utf-8")

    try:
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data_str)
        message_id = future.result()
        return https_fn.Response(json.dumps({"message": "Message published", "message_id": message_id}), status=200)
    except Exception as e:
        return https_fn.Response(json.dumps({"error": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"}), status=500)


@pubsub_fn.on_message_published(
    topic = "youtube",
    timeout_sec = 540,
    memory = options.MemoryOption.GB_32
)
def youtube_trigger(event: pubsub_fn.CloudEvent[pubsub_fn.MessagePublishedData]) -> None:
    print("!!! youtube_trigger runs for the first-time !!!")

We have confirmed the message is placed without issue.
curl http://127.0.0.1:5001/XXX/us-central1/youtube_request \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -d '{ "uid": "123", "doc_id": "456", "filename": "https://youtu.be/YYY", "language": "en" }'
{"message": "Message published", "message_id": "1"}


Other steps I have tried :
My guess is, maybe there is an issue of pub/sub emulator comes with Firebase.
Hence, I try to replace it with Google Cloud pub/sub emulator using the following way.

firebase emulators:start --only firestore,functions,auth,storage,ui
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=XXX

Still, I am getting
function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.

I can confirm the pub/sub emulator is running, because I can place message into it without error.
But, the subscribe function doesn't run.
It seems like pub/sub emulator is running, but functions emulator is not able to discover it?
